# Numeric compare of two xml nodes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I have a column `XMLRECORD` of `XML` type in a table called `ABCD`.

My records contain:

```
<row id="100" xml:space="preserve">
  <c9>400</c9>
  <c10>4000</c10>
</row>

<row id="90" xml:space="preserve">
  <c9>324</c9>
  <c10>34</c10>
</row>
```

I am trying to compare the two nodes of this `XMLRECORD` using the query

```
SELECT XMLRECORD 
FROM ABCD  
WHERE XMLRECORD.exist(N'/row[c9/text() < c10/text()]') = 1
```

When executed in SQL Server it displays both the records doing the ASCII compare. How to force the SQL Server to go for a numeric compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert it to number inside xpath:

```
select *
from ABCD 
where xmlrecord.exist('/row[number((c9/text())[1]) < number((c10/text())[1])]') = 1
```

or compare values:

```
select *
from ABCD 
where xmlrecord.value('(/row/c9/text())[1]', 'int') < xmlrecord.value('(/row/c10/text())[1]', 'int')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply.  Will the performance get a hit by using the number() inside exist?

Comment: @user2902029 I suggest to check it on your data, I think that first one should be faster than second, but may be a bit slower than one without number (as in your question).